# sorting NSArray of NSDictionaries in which are array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, nspredicate

i need sorting my array with "Date" key of items dictionary.And in the end i need array with some structure as my mData array but with sorting Date.

`mData---------->(
        {
        items =         (
                        {
                Accuracy = 5;
                Address = "Australia, Sydney CBD, Bridge Street";
                Course = "0.00";
                Date = "2013-08-20 06:50:28 +0000";
                Speed = 3;
                alt = 0;
                lat = "-33.8634";
                lon = "151.211";
            },
                        {
                Accuracy = 65;
                Address = "Armenia, Yerevan, \U053f\U0561\U056c\U0565\U0576\U0581\U056b \U0583\U0578\U0572\U0578\U0581";
                Course = "0.00";
                Date = "2013-08-20 06:41:02 +0000";
                Speed = 3;
                alt = 1116;
                lat = "40.20016076";
                lon = "44.49`enter code here`130268";
            }
        );
        name = Name;
        startTime = "10:40";
    }
)`
*my array looked like* 
2.`NSDictionary * mFirst = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate distantFuture], @"Date", nil];
    NSDictionary * mSecond = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate distantPast], @"Date", nil];
    NSArray *mArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:mFirst,mSecond, nil];
    NSDictionary * myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mArr forKey:@"items"];
    NSArray * mSortedArray = [[ NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:myDict, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", mSortedArray);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

**UPDATED:**
I have used this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate distantFuture], @"Date", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDate distantPast], @"Date", nil], nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

And got log:

**Before sorting:**
 *(
        {
        Date = "4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    },
        {
        Date = "0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000";
    }
)*
**After sorting:** 
*(
        {
        Date = "0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000";
    },
        {
        Date = "4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    }
)*

Please check while using above code.

Comment: have you NSLog sortedArray?

Comment: Yes but i can't post it here ---too long by 951 characters

Comment: You have array of dictionary and you want to sort your array according to date key in your dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary will come at it was but you'll get sorted array according to date key.

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to sort my array with Date key in ascending order

Comment: if you want to sort array of dictionary with its key the this is the code. Please check it. Use your array instead of myArray.

Comment: i use this code ` NSSortDescriptor *  dateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES] ;
    myNewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
 NSArray *   sortedArray = [mReturningValue sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:myNewArray];
`

Comment: Please use above code as it is and replace myArray with the array which you want to sort. Thats it.

Comment: no effect:( here is my date key values from 0 index off array to 3 index ` Date = "2013-08-20 07:49:50 +0000"; Date = "2013-08-20 07:51:28 +0000"; Date = "2013-08-20 07:49:22 +0000"; Date = "2013-08-20 07:50:29 +0000";`

Comment: Date = "2013-08-20 08:05:27 +0000"; Date = "2013-08-20 08:05:27 +0000";Date = "2013-08-20 08:04:49 +0000"; Date = "2013-08-20 08:07:07 +0000"; I try but...